# Getting a nil error when adding to a table using '<<' in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So here's the setup:

The controller is passing these two to the view:

```
@courses = Course.all
@assignments = Assignment.all
```

```
<% this_assignment = Assignment.create(instructor: "test") %>
<% @assignments << this_assignment %>
```

The Assignment model has (among others) the attribute `instructor` which is a string value.

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

What's weird is I do the same thing for course earlier in the code and it seems to work fine. I'm sure it's some simple fix but I can't seem to figure out why `<<` works for `@courses` but not for `@assignments`.

Comment: @assignments is nil. Does *Assignment* have an *all* method?

Comment: Yes. The controller is written as: @assignments = Assignment.all

Answer (score 1):

this is unnecessary to do:

```
<% @assignments << this_assignment %>
```

@assignments will include all the records each time the page is loaded. If the page is refreshing the variable will have all of the assignments in it.

you also shouldn't have that create action in the view. It will create a record every time you load the page.

Remove trying to push to @assignments and you should be fine. Refresh and it'll be there.

Comment: Well this is mainly an example. The page itself will need to create new assignments and add them to the @assignments by running through certain constraints. I was just doing a test to see if I would run in to any problems during the set up. If I'm not explaining this well enough please let me know, but doing this is part of the purpose of the view.

Comment: You still shouldn't be doing object creation in a view... this is a big code-smell and it means you probably should change the way things are being done so they aren't being done in the view. We can help you with that if you write up what you've tried in code, why you think you have to do it that way and what you are trying to really achieve... as a new question.

Comment: Just piling on... Taryn East and toddmetheny are RIGHT AS RAIN. No object creation in the view. Bad. Very bad. It makes my eyes hurt.

Answer (score 1):

If you receive this error message, then `@assignments` is nil.
Try and print it out or use `byebug` to verify.

These reason come to mind:

- Typo in the controller
- Controller action is not called
- There is more code that we don't see